# Binding to properties of object within View Model WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

In my class 'ScheduleViewModel' I have the following property:

```
private ReminderFilter filter;
public ReminderFilter Filter
{
 get { return filter; }
 set
 {
     filter = value;
     NotifyPropertyChanged("Filter");
 }
}
```

What I would like to do is bind to the properties of this object without needing to expose them in the View Model. I have tried the following XAML with no success:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Filter.Complete, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Content="Show Completed"></CheckBox>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a quick question, does the `ReminderFilter` implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` too? Because (afaik) `Filter.Complete` binding should work.

Comment: did you checked the data binding errors ? whether you have initialized the property?

Comment: I just changed the ReminderFilter to implement INotifyPropertyChanged but after changing the CheckBoxes IsChecked the set of Complete was not even called. What might i have done wrong?

Comment: Show the XAML that binds the view Datacontext to your VieModel or all what this checkbox is contained in. it smells the binding couldn't find the right datacontext

Comment: <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="scheduleSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance VM:ScheduleViewModel, CreateList=True}" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource scheduleSource}">
</Grid>

Comment: Binding is done the same in this control as in all of my other working controls. And the datacontext on other checkboxes are the same as in working controls.

Comment: Is Filter actually instantiated somewhere?

Comment: Yes, on the ScheduleViewmodels constructer I instantiate Filter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two-way binding.  Oneway will only update the view.  If you check the checkbox, the value doesn't propagate back down to the object.

Comment: I changed the Mode to Two Way and it still does not call the set of the Complete property.

Comment: Check the data binding errors in the output console.  This checkbox may not have the datacontext of this viewmodel.

Comment: I checked the datacontext of the checkbox and it is set correctly.

Comment: When the application is running, view the Output window Ctrl+W,O .  Any errors in databinding will be visible there.

Comment: I could not find any databinding errors in the output window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid exposing the property in the view model you will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the ReminderFilter model.

[Similar SO Discussion on Get Notified when model properties change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931323/get-notified-when-properties-change-in-the-model)

I know you said you would rather not expose the property in the view model but if you were against implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in the model:

```
    private ReminderFilter filter;
    public bool FilterComplete
    {
        get
        {
            return filter.Complete;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == filter.Complete)
                return;
            filter.Complete = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterComplete");
        }
    }
```

xaml:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding FilterComplete}" Content="Show Completed"></CheckBox>
```