# If my dependency property is a class how do I get property changed to activate on a class property change?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

So I have something like this:

```
class ViewModel
{
    Dependency Property User User;
    public bool IsDirty;

    override OnPropertyChanged
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged();
        this.IsDirty = true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that OnPropertyChanged does not trigger unless I reassign the User object. How can I get it to trigger when a property of User changes? For example when I have one User object, but User.FirstName changes. Danke.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931323/get-notified-when-properties-change-in-the-model

Comment: [DependencyProperties don't belong into ViewModels](http://kentb.blogspot.com.ar/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one of the properties of `User` must also notify on change.

E.g.:

```
public class User
{
    string _Name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set {
            _Name = value;
            PropertyChanged("Name");
        }
...
    }
}
```