# Get edited GridView item when EditingElement is unknown

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have a UserControl, which is basically a wrapper for a GridView that needs to send a message every time a cell content (of the GridView) is changed. Usually, that could be solved like this:

```
private void MainDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        var editingTextBox = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
        doSomething(editingTextBox.Text);
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know the type of EditingElement (which comes as a FrameworkElement) so I cannot do the conversion. And in that moment, the *currentCell.SelectedValue* is still the original value. I also don't have control over the model (where I could implement *INotifyPropertyChanged* and use it to catch the changes).

Is there some simple way I am missing? Or how would you go about implementing this? Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a very simple solution (can't belive I haven't seen that one) composed of catching two events from the DataGrid. 
Here is the code:

```
private object changedRow;

    private void MainDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        changedRow = e.Row.Item;
    }

    private void MainDataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (changedRow != null)
        {
            // do something with the edited row here
            changedRow = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your model within a `CollectionView` and use this for the binding.

```
myCollectionView = (CollectionView)
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(rootElem.DataContext);
```

This will provide you a `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

**Update**
Sorry my first answer was somewhat misleading.

If you're not able to change the model, you should create a view model. The view model, implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` can provide the needed change events without any knowledge of the current view. This way the view doesn't depend directly on the model.

Futher reading:
[The role of the model in MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027562/the-role-of-the-model-in-mvvm)

Comment: Could you provide a sample on how would I go about retrieving changes from the CollectionView? The only events I see on the CollectionView are CurrentChanging / CurrentChanged and even those are fired only when I sort the collection, not when I change the selected cell. Thanks